# What is wrong with this DDL for creating an index on a SQL Server CE Table?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-ce, ddl

With this code:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, Description nvarchar(255), DeptDotSubdept float, UnitCost float, UnitList float, UPCCode nvarchar(50), UPCPackSize smallint, CRVId int);"
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX idxUnitCost ON InventoryItems (UnitCost) ASC";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

...I get, "*There was an error parsing the query .... Token in error = ASC*"

Is my "ASC" in the wrong location, or...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE [CLUSTERED| NONCLUSTERED] INDEX idxUnitCost --<-- Type of Index [CLUSTERED OR NONCLUSTERED] 
> ON InventoryItems (UnitCost ASC)         --<-- Order Inside the Parenthesis
> ```

Comment: Oh, the "ASC" has to go inside the parens after the column name?

Comment: I think somebody thought your syntax was saying to both cluster and noncluster; their comment is gone, so they must have deleted it.

Comment: Yes with the column name, if you have multiple column name than next to the one you want your index to be ordered by like (Column1, Column2 ASC)

Comment: No I mentioned two primary options and placed them in square bracket to explain that your Type of Index goes there, some people are quick to down vote anyway :)